# setting up Flask db migrations with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, flask-migrate, sqlalchemy-migrate

I have set up a site built on Flask sing `eb` (the Terminal client for Elastic Beanstalk v3.1).

When deploying a new version of my site I get "Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation." message.

I have `.ebextensions/aws.config` file

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "application.py db upgrade"
    leader_only: true
```

I tried using `ignoreErrors: true` and different combinations for the command with no luck. Any ideas to solve this or get away with migration upgrades?

versions:

```
alembic==0.7.4
awsebcli==3.1
cement==2.4.0
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Migrate==1.3.0
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
jmespath==0.6.1
Mako==1.0.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
psycopg2==2.6
python-dateutil==2.4.0
PyYAML==3.11
six==1.9.0
SQLAlchemy==0.9.8
Werkzeug==0.10.1
```

Eerything deployed with Python 3.4 on a 64bit Debian jessie v1.2.0 running Python 3.4 (Preconfigured - Docker)

EDIT: after the misspelling fix
Event message:

```
[Instance: i-a1627aab Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] command failed with error code 1: Error occurred during build: Command 01_migrate failed.
```

these are the logs from Elastic Beanstalk

```
[2015-02-22T23:37:16.010Z] INFO  [17720] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Activity execution failed, because: command failed with error code 1: Error occurred during build: Command 01_migrate failed (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
    at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executor-1.0/lib/executor/exec.rb:81:in `sh'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executor-1.0/lib/executor/exec.rb:24:in `sh'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/cfn-wrapper.rb:51:in `call_cfn_script'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/cfn-wrapper.rb:28:in `run_config_sets'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/infrahooks/infra-embeddedpostbuild.rb:20:in `execute!'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/executable.rb:56:in `instance_eval'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/executable.rb:56:in `execute!'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:213:in `block (3 levels) in exec_stage'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `exec'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:126:in `timeout_exec'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:110:in `block in create'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `instance_eval'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `create'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:209:in `block (2 levels) in exec_stage'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:207:in `each'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:207:in `each_with_index'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:207:in `block in exec_stage'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `exec'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:126:in `timeout_exec'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:110:in `block in create'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `instance_eval'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `create'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:204:in `exec_stage'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:158:in `execute!'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:68:in `run'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in execute!'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `exec'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:126:in `timeout_exec'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:110:in `block in create'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `instance_eval'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `create'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:62:in `block in execute!'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:106:in `execute_command'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:60:in `execute!'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/bin/command-processor:46:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in `load'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: you could try to spell upgrade correctly on this line command: "application.py db updagre"

Comment: dumb me, fixed the misspelling. But still having the error.

Comment: Perhaps ssh into the ec2 and run command manually to see more detail

Comment: ok, I SSHed into the EC2, first thing that I found super wrong, is that the virtualenv was created with python 2.7 instead of 3.4 :#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665911/python3-command-not-found-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-64bit-debian-jessie-v1-2-0?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1):

@dnuske

Please note that the solution stack you are using is a Docker based solution stack. As a result, your eb-extensions will not run within the docker context but within the host.

To do what you require, you'll need to update the python dockerfile (https://github.com/aws/aws-eb-python-dockerfiles/blob/master/3.4.2-aws-eb-onbuild/Dockerfile ) to add the upgrade step as part of that docker file. Once you have done that, you can bundle your docker file along with your application and your steps will work as required.

Please let me know if that answers your question.

Thanks,
Dhanvi

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are in the necessary python virtual environment for the migration. In my instance I found the following to work for Flask-Migrate:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate; flask db upgrade"
    leader_only: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this file to the root of your project directory:

`.ebextensions/migration.config`

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && python3 manage.py db upgrade"
    leader_only: true
```

Check `PYTHONPATH` in your EB environment configuration / Software / Environment properties. Mine is `/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin`

`manage.py` is the file that contains something like this

```
import os
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

from application import application, db


application.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

migrate = Migrate(application, db)
manager = Manager(application)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```