# Python3: command not found on AWS Elastic Beanstalk "64bit Debian jessie v1.2.0 running Python 3.4"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a new instance using EB cli 3.1. When I SSH into it, I type in python3 and it error with Command not found.

```
$ python3
-bash: python3: command not found
```

I tried installing it but "yum search python3" does not find any 3.x version. 
How do I get it to install Python3.4 when I exec `eb deploy` ?
(BTW Why the title says with python3.4 while not having it?)

Comment: Which version does `python` invoke?

Comment: Python 2.6.9 (unknown, Sep 13 2014, 00:25:11)

Comment: Also, Debian uses apt, not yum. Are you sure you're running Debian?

Comment: when I SSH it welcomes with "Amazon Linux AMI - https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.09-release-notes/" yet on the AWS console, in the dashboard it says "Configuration: 

64bit Debian jessie v1.2.0 running Python 3.4 (Preconfigured - Docker)"

Comment: i think you may need to attach to your docker container / image / instance and use the python within the docker, and not within debian.

Comment: you are correct, now I'm doing it with docker and goes ok. The problem started when I followed an AWS guide on how to use ´eb´ yikes!